# how to do union of 2 scala.collection.mutable.Seq in java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I want to get the union of 2 `scala.collection.mutable.Seq` in java Spark.

I am using the following udf to perform the action :

```
sqlContext.udf().register("unionSets", (Seq<String> s1, Seq<String> s2) -> 
insert union function here, DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType));
```

Being new to spark, I do not understand how to work with the union function provided by SeqLike class :

```
<B, That> That union(scala.collection.GenSeq<B> genSeq,       
scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom<Repr,B,That> canBuildFrom);
```

I have my data in the following form : 
dataFrame :

`Id(type : long) | NameList (type : WrappedArray)`

Id is not unique and i want to group by Id. Hence i need to use union as an aggregate function on NameList column.